# Клик по динамически созданному элементу

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Есть такой момент, что если элемент, в котором есть дочерние элементы есть в html верстке, то клик по нему определяется корректно,

```
<button class="vsfm_control-btn" data-command="closeFmModal">
      <i class="icon-clear"></i>
      <span class="vsfm_control-btn-text">Закрыть</span>
</button>
```

```
let toolBtn = document.querySelectorAll('button')
        toolBtn.forEach(function(b) {
            if (b.disabled) return
            b.addEventListener('click', command, false)
        })
```

а если кнопка создается динамически скриптом, и вставляется таким образом

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', btn)
```

то клик по кнопке ловится только тогда, когда курсор не находится над элементами i и span, то есть где то в уголке кнопки. Подскажите, чем лечить?

Comment: воспроизведите тут проблему, а то отрывками накидали

Comment: Да все же вроде описал, если кнопка есть в живую в html разметке, то клик ловится нормально, куда не кликни в кнопку, получаем e.dataset.command. А  если эта кнопка генерируется в javascript и динамически вставляется в DOM, то клик по кнопке срабатывает только если курсор установлен в зоне кнопки, но НЕ НАД элементами i или span, где то в уголках кнопки. Если кликнуть прямо в надпись "Закрыть", мы получаем клик не по button, а по его дочернему элементу span,